# How to make an vector of abstract template class

Tags: c++, templates, vector, virtual, abstract

Following does not work:

```
std::vector<IRule*> vec;
RuleRangeDouble *rule = new RuleRangeDouble(0, 100);
vec.push_back(rule);
```

Now how can a make a vector of different rules? I know, I have to use pointers... But what else do I have to do to get this working? How can I change my base structure to get this work?

I use an Interface like the following:

```
// Interface
    template <typename T>
    class IRule
    {
        public:
            virtual bool isValid(T value) = 0;
    };
```

And my example class looks like this:

```
class RuleRangeDouble : public IRule<double>
    {
        private:
            double min;
            double max;
        public:

            bool isValid(double value)
            {
....
            };
    };
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work?  If `RuleRangeDouble` derives publicly from `IRule`, there's no reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: @JamesKanze It is down to `IRule` being a class template.

Comment: @juanchopanza I missed that.  If `IRule` is a template, `IRule*` is not a valid type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement something like `getBestValidValue()`in several ways. One is to define a special general (but non-template) return type to be used for `getBestValidValue()` and also as argument type for `isValid(value)` (juanchopanza's answer was faulty here):

```
class ValueType
{
  enum { is_int, is_double } my_type;  // add more if you want
  union { my_int; my_double; };        // union only works for simple types
public:
  // implicit construction from allowed types
  ValueType(int x) : my_type(is_int), my_int(x) {}
  ValueType(double x) : my_type(is_double), my_double(x) {}
  // use SFINAE for is<type>() function
  template<typename T>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T,int>::value,bool>::type
  is() const { return my_type==is_int; }
  template<typename T>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T,double>::value,bool>::type
  is() const { return my_type==is_double; }
  // implicit type conversion to allowed types
  // note: does not assert(is<T>())
  operator int() { return my_int; }
  operator double() { return my_double; }
};

class IRule
{
public:
  virtual bool isValid(ValueType const&) const = 0; // fixed bug in juanchopanza's answer
  virtual ValueType getBestValidValue() const = 0;  // return any type of value
  virtual ~IRule() {}
};

template<typename T>
class Rule : public IRule
{
protected:
  virtual bool valid(T) const = 0; 
  virtual T bestValidValue() const = 0;
public:
  bool isValid(ValueType const&value) const
  {
    return value.is<T>()
        && valid(value);         // implicit type conversion to T
  }
  ValueType getBestValidValue() const
  {
    return bestValidValue();     // implicit construction of ValueType
  }
  ....
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I got this solution to work and it does what I want. I only can't use `std::enable_if` because I've to use Visual Studio 2005 and the library is not part of it...

Comment: @prom85 you can define your own `enable_if` easily: `template<bool=true, typename T=void> struct enable_if { typedef T type; };` and `template<typename> struct enable_if<false,T> {};`

Answer (score 3):

The vector needs to be a vector of an actual type, for example `std::vector<IRule<double>*>`. `Irule` on its own is not a type, it is a class template. So you would need

```
std::vector<IRule<double>*> vec;
RuleRangeDouble *rule = new RuleRangeDouble(0, 100);
vec.push_back(rule);
```

If the template parameter is not part of the interface, you can introduce a common base class. Don't forget to give it a `virtual` destructor:

```
class IRule
{
    public:
        virtual bool isValid(T value) = 0;
        virtual ~IRule() {}
};

template <typename T>
class Rule : public IRule 
{
  .....
};

class RuleRangeDouble : public Rule<double>
{
  ....
};
```

Then your original use case sample would work:

```
std::vector<IRule*> vec; // IRule really is a type now
RuleRangeDouble *rule = new RuleRangeDouble(0, 100);
vec.push_back(rule);
```

Comment: That's my problem, I want a vector of undefined type, just the pointer... I want to call isValid for all objects in my vector... No matter what type they are... Because there are more classes than just the RuleRangeDouble class.. I don't know, maybe some wrapper solution exists for that? I just can't think of one... and I couldn't get anyone I found to work...

Comment: @prom85 then you need a common base class, or a variant type such as `boost::any` or `boost::variant`.

Comment: actually, I don't know how you mean that, a base class would have to be above the `IRule` interface and therefore needs to be a template as well... and I can't use boost, unfortunately...

Comment: @prom85 no, the point is the common base class it cannot be a template. A class template is not a type, it is a template to make a type. The vector needs an actual type.

Comment: so this means, it's not possible to achieve what I want in c++? A vector which holds objects which all implement the same interface so that I can just run through the vector and call the interface function? Not, if the Interface is a template?

Comment: @prom85 I think you can achieve what you want, but with a common, non-template base class, iff the interfaces are really the same.

Comment: I could change the interface to `bool isValid()` but I would also need a function like `T getBestValidValue()`... so I need a template...

Comment: @prom85 that is not possible. The interface would be different anyway.